# Jest - function not calling its child async function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, mobx

I am writing a unit test in Jest for my React `Login` component. The component has a `handleLoginSubmit` method which gets called when form is submitted. This method is actually defined in my `store`, and a reference is passed to the `Login` component.

store.js:

```
handleLoginSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const result = await service.validateUser(this.username, this.password);
    if (result) {
        this.isAuthenticated = true;
        this.invalidLogin = false;
        history.push('/search');
    }
    else this.invalidLogin = true;
}
```

I have written the test case to check if the `Login` component calls `handleSubmit` when form is submitted, and whether authentication is done correctly:

login.test.js

```
describe('Login should authenticate users corectly when', () => {

    it('correct credentials are submitted', async () => {
        const spySubmit = jest.spyOn(store, 'handleLoginSubmit');
        const spyValidate = jest.spyOn(service, 'validateUser');
        const wrapper = shallow(<Login store={store} />);
        expect(spySubmit).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(0);
        wrapper.find('form').simulate('submit');
        expect(spySubmit).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
        expect(spyValidate).toBeCalledWith({ username: store.username, password: store.password });
    });
});
```

service.js:

```
export function validateUser(username, password) {
    return fetch(`https://abc.co/api?search=${username}`)
        .then(function (response) {
            return response.json();
        }).then(function (response) {
            if (response.results.length) {
                if (response.results[0].key === password) {
                    return true;
                }
                else return false;
            }
            else return false;
        });
}
```

But the test fails with message 'spyValidate was not called'. So my question is, why is `service.validateUser` is not called, even though `handleLoginSubmit` is being called successfully? I believe it has something to do with async? What's the correct way to test the authentication functionality of `Login`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is what you `expect`ed is not the mocked method. You should expect the mocked method like this:

```
expect(store.handleLoginSubmit).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(0)
```

and similar to other `expect`.

In the end of your test case, you should restore the mocked method by calling [`.mockRestore()`](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/mock-function-api.html#mockfnmockrestore):

```
store.handleLoginSubmit.mockRestore()
```

If after this, you still get issue with async call, here's my suggestion that makes your tests be more ...unit test: You should separate the test into 2 test cases, one to test if `store.handleLoginSubmit` is called after form is submitted, and the other one is to test what inside `store.handleLoginSubmit`,

```
test('.handleLoginSubmit() called when form is submitted', () => {
  jest.spyOn(store, 'handleLoginSubmit').mockImplementation(() => {})
  const wrapper = shallow(<Login store={store} />);
  wrapper.find('form').simulate('submit');
  expect(store.handleLoginSubmit).toBeCalled()
  store.handleLoginSubmit.mockRestore()
})

test('.handleLoginSubmit()', async () => {
  jest.spyOn(service, 'validateUser')
    .mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve(true))
  await store.handleLoginSubmit({preventDefault: () => {}})
  expect(service.validateUser).toBeCalled()
  service.validateUser.mockRestore()
})
```